# What is an alternative to JSON for storing key-value pairs and that can be easily parsed using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to store some data on the server in form of key,value pairs which will be transmitted to the frontend and converted to javascript arrays for further processing. I chose the JSON format and built a small json db. For some reason I was using 'jquery 1.3.2' for testing and when I shifted to 'jquery 1.6.2', my code stopped working and I figured out that thats because of invalid JSON which jquery (1.4+) silently ignores.

> As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error, the
>   request will usually fail silently. Avoid frequent hand-editing of
>   JSON data for this reason. JSON is a data-interchange format with
>   syntax rules that are stricter than those of JavaScript's object
>   literal notation.

So whats a good, low bandwidth alternative for json which is easy to parse with Jquery, which can be easily hand-edited and is not so strict about syntax? (Not that I intend to make syntax errors, but in case there's one, don't want everything to stop working)

Alternatively, is there a way to force jquery to parse invalid JSON?

Comment: Can we see a sample of your invalid JSON?

Comment: You really ought to just fix your JSON to be legal JSON and use the tools the way they are meant to be used.  It is not hard to generate legal JSON either programmatically or by hand.  You just need to follow the appropriate rules.  If you post your JSON, folks here will help you understand where it went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the jQuery core team members posted this workaround to get pre-1.4 functionality for JSON:

```
$.ajax({url: "/url", 
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(json) {
    // do something with json
  }
});

// becomes

$.ajax({url: "/url",
  dataType: "text",
  success: function(text) {
    json = eval("(" + text + ")");
    // do something with JSON
  }
});
```

http://yehudakatz.com/2010/01/15/jquery-1-4-and-malformed-json/

Is this along the lines of what you're looking for?

Comment: To quote that page, _"You should probably be modifying your busted server-side code to stop sending malformed JSON!"_

Comment: This is true, if you are emitting bad JSON from your server code (ie, `{ serverKey: "serverValue" }` , but there are definitely times when this is out of your control and you don't want to silently ignore it.

Comment: This is a hack and should only be considered if better solutions cannot be found.  The better solution in this case is to just fix the mal-formed JSON to be proper JSON.  Putting one hack on top of mal-formed JSON to get something working is not the mark of quality programming.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to pass the JSON through a validator such as [JSONLint](http://www.jsonlint.com) and then implement error avoiding code?  You can use the eval() workaround as this is completely valid.  You will just want to be careful when using data from a third-party location as it can contain malicious commands.

Depending on the extent of the data you are passing, you may be able to output the data in a delimited fashion and just use a simple $.ajax() call to separate the delimited data via a loop and handle it accordingly.